# Design and architecture solutions to break a monolithic "NON web based local host application"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, monolithic, non-web

I am looking at pointers for design and architecture solutions to break a monolithic application. This application is a non-web, localhost application. How can I do this using Microservices, Kubernetes, Dockers?  Are Dockers, Kubernetes and Microservices design patterns only applicable to Web-based apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://microservices.io/refactoring/index.html) is a good starting point describing patterns for refactoring monolith app to microservices.

It also contains two examples there with the same application: [one](https://github.com/microservices-patterns/ftgo-monolith) being the monolithic and the same microservices based [one](https://github.com/microservices-patterns/ftgo-application) so that you can see how exactly it was refactored into small pieces.

Answer (score 1):

There is some good information around that question here:

- https://thenewstack.io/containerize-legacy-applications-not/

Network applications, that you have the source code for, make ideal candidates. Web nicely fits into the model since it works on TCP/IP stack. There are other use-cases out there as well but don't fit naturally.